# non-rectangurlar shaped java UserControl

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, components, controls

- In .NET a **UserControl** may be composed of Controls and it may be part of a Form or part of a bigger UserControl. One can design UserControls with a Visual Designer using the ToolBox Palette.
- I have found out that a java **BeanForm** is the analouge for a .NET UserControl.
- I can design a BeanForm with a visual Designer in NetBeans
- In my Library I can extend a BeanForm from any other Library and I can design the extended BeanForm with a visual Designer in NetBeans.
- In my main Project I can pick all my BeanForms from the **Palette** onto my frames.

So "BeanForm" is the java pendant for the "UserControl".

---

In .Net I can easily shape my UserControl to a Fish or to a Star or to whatever I like
by simply setting this.Region = new Region(graphicsPath).

---

I know that Java is not as easy as C# and I have found Java Samples that **partly** describe the necessary steps BUT 
I did not find a **Shaped non-rectangular BeanForm** Sample.

---

Of course extending the MouseAdapter with a new special mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) -- as many Samples do suggest -- isnt enough - this is only a first step.

- **Did they all forget about the Dragged-Event and the Focus Events and the Mouse-Entered Event and Mouse-Up Event and Mouse-Leave Event and all the other typical JComponent Events ???** - Such Component will **SURELY NOT BEHAVE** like a real Shaped JComponent should behave.

---

Please give me a Sample for a OvalComponent-BeanForm that can be taken from the Palette onto my frame and that will behave like a **REAL Shaped JComponent**

It should cover All the necessary Mouse Events and all the necessary MouseMotion Events and all the Drag-Drop Events and all the Key-Events in case the Oval has the focus or in case the Mouse is over the Oval.

(e.g I should be enabled to use the Oval's Mouse Events and to extend the Oval Component to a MovingOval Component that can be moved around within the frame ...)

---

If this is too much work for you then, please, outline and describe the steps I would have to implement - like MouseAdapter, KeyAdapter, maybe DragDropAdapter or whatever is necessary.

please, point me what to do!

many thanks in advance.

Comment: Any component is always going to be rectangular.  Having said that, you can use opacity to change the areas that are clickable/visible.  You can also effect the clip shape (but I'd be very careful with this) OR you can change the shape of the top level container it self.  The other problem is, do you want the child components to "fit" into the shape or should they be clipped?

Comment: okay, MadProgrammer, you are right and I should clarify it:
behind the scenes every Control Component is rectangular in C# and in Java!
In order to behave like a non-rectangular Control Component some regions must be transparent AND MOREOVER these regions MUST NOT react to Mouse-Events and/or DragDrop Events.
One can achive this "non-rectangualr" behaviour with 1 code line in C# but in java there is no solution so far.
For now I dont care for the "inner Components" (I do not plan to have "inner Controls")
I would be happy if there was a solution for the "shaped control problem".
yours, Gerald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `java.awt.Shape` has a `contains()` method that you can use for hit testing in your `MouseListener` or `Mouseadapter`.

Comment: many thanks, overriding the contains(x, y) method works really well!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, no one answered so far.
I want to put it differently.

---

Let us suppose we have 2 square CirclePanels (extends JPanel), size 100x100 pixels, each shaped to a cicle and these 2 Components show a red cicle and a blue circle.
And let us suppose that the CirclePanels are transparent in the regions outside the colored circles.
And let us furthermore suppose that the hosting frame has Null-Layout - so the red circle partly overlaps the blue circle.

In order to make these circles behave like real Controls we have to fix at least these issues:

1.) a MouseClick outside the circles but very very close to the circle's border must ONLY trigger  the frame's MouseListener - it MUST NOT trigger the JPanel'S MouseListeners.

2.) a MouseClick inside the red area must ONLY trigger the red JPanel's MouseListener - it MUST NOT trigger the blue JPanel'S MouseListener and it MUST NOT trigger the frame's MouseListener.

3.) a MouseClick inside the blue area must ONLY trigger the blue JPanel's MouseListener - it MUST NOT trigger the red JPanel'S MouseListener and it MUST NOT trigger the frame's MouseListener.

4.) The necessary Source Code to achieve this all MUST be within the CirclePanel.java file and the frame's java MUST NOT care for these issues. This is because these shaped Controls have to function in ANY frame.

This describes the requirement differently.

Can anybody, please, point me now, how it can be done in java.
yours, Gerald

Comment: I think you're supposed to update your question to bump it up in the "active" questions queue.